# .htaccess - Remove trailing slash if site URL starts with a certain domain on

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

On WordPress, I have a few 301 redirects on my site that redirects the user to an external site
Those 301 redirects have been adding a trailing slash, here's the code for it:

```
Redirect 301 /12345 https://example.com/survey/?query=12345
```

So the above redirect redirects the user to `https://example.com/survey/?query=12345/` which causes a 404

I would like to remove the trailing slash from all URLs if they start with `www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this rule using `RedirectMatch` that uses regex matching:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(12345) https://example.com/survey/?query=$1
```

And make sure:

- Above rule is **first rule** in your .htaccess
- You test in a new browser to avoid old cache

---

For your 2nd part of question of removing all trailing slash from `www.example.com` you will need to place a rule in site root .htaccess or Apache server of `example.com` host:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: For the second part, I unfortunately don't have access to the .htaccess of the www.example.com host

Comment: Yes in that case you cannot control behavior on `example.com`